# Помогите с MySQL запросом связанный с выборкой

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Всем привет. Помогите сделать mysql запрос.Суть такова есть 2 таблицы: incomes(Приход) и users(Пользователи)
[image: incomes(Приход)]
[image: users(Пользователи)]

У таблицы incomes поле **id_selected_user** и **id_user** являются внешними ключами и ссылаются на первичный ключ **id_user** в таблице users.
Нужно сделать запрос, который вместо цифр в полях **id_selected_user** и **id_user** выводил имя пользователя из таблиц users.
Пробовал с помощью джоинов, но получается вывести только 1 имя

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *,users1.Name,users2.Name from incomes
Left Join users AS users1 on incomes.id_selected_user = users1.id_user
Left Join users AS users2 on incomes.id_user = users1.id_user
```

Но при условии что не бывает нескольких записей с одинаковым users.id_user

Comment: Спасибо. Именно то, что нужно было.